# Array.push() doesn't affect outer .then scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

The second part of a lambda function after first fetch request:

```
.then((articles) => {
  var images = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    fetch(
      `example.com/${articles}`
    )
      .then((image) => image.json())
      .then((image) => {
        images.push([
          image["parse"]["title"],
          image["parse"]["images"][
            Math.floor(Math.random() * image["parse"]["images"].length)
          ],
        ]);
        console.log(images); \\ logs expected
      });
  }
  console.log(images); \\ logs empty array
  return images;
})
```

How can the `.push()` change the outer `images` variable?

Comment: it's showing an empty array because the fetch hasn't been done yet because it's asynchronous

Comment: It does affect the outer scoped array.  You're just doing a `console.log(images)` BEFORE the asynchronous operations in the loop have completed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does affect the outer scoped array. You're just doing a console.log(images) BEFORE the asynchronous operations in the loop have completed.

Since you have a loop of asynchronous operations and they can all run in parallel, I would suggest using `.map()` to traverse the loop and build the output array of promises for you and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all those promises to be done and collect all the results in order.  You can do that like this:

```
.then((articles) => {
  return Promise.all(articles.map(article => {
      return fetch(`http://example.com/${article}`)
        .then(image => image.json())
        .then(image => {
            return [
            image.parse.title,
            image.parse.images[
              Math.floor(Math.random() * image["parse"]["images"].length)
          ];
        });
  })).then(allImages => {
      // this .then() handler is only here to we can log the final result
      console.log(allImages);
      return allImages;
  });
})
```